# Assembly reflection loading and app domain conflict

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to make a small C# tool to compare two svn revision builds and track properties changes in any classes. My goal is to use reflection to compare the properties of each class of my dll without using Momo.Cecil.

From experimenting, then reading this article [Assembly Loading](http://codeidol.com/csharp/net-framework/Assemblies,-Loading,-and-Deployment/Assembly-Loading/) and a few threads found on Google, I learnt that two DLLs with same identities would get resolved as the same if we dont use `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`.

Trying to use their code to create an AppDomain for each loading, and also try many variants from searches, I get this exception and I can't find any thread explaining how to solve this issue:

> API restriction: The assembly 'file:///D:\somepath\82\MyLib.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.

This error happen on the 2nd call (the path 82) on the following line:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
```

Maybe I din't understand something very basic which make me unable to create a new AppDomain correctly?

### Here is all the code used to reproduce this problem.

Code from my entry point

```
        //Let say one of the property has been renamed between both commits
        var svnRev81Assembly = ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"D:\somepath\81\MyLib.dll");
        var svnRev82Assembly = ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(@"D:\somepath\82\MyLib.dll");
```

Implementation of the loader

```
    private string _CurrentAssemblyKey;
    private Assembly ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(string assemblyPath)
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);

        // Create application domain setup information.
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = path;
        domaininfo.PrivateBinPath = path;

        _CurrentAssemblyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        AppDomain currentAd = AppDomain.CreateDomain(_CurrentAssemblyKey, null, domaininfo); //Everytime we create a new domain with a new name        
        //currentAd.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve += CustomReflectionOnlyResolver; This doesnt work anymore since I added AppDomainSetup        
        currentAd.SetData(_CurrentAssemblyKey, path);

        //Loading to specific location -  folder 81 or 82
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);

        //Preloading the 
        foreach (var assemblyName in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(Path.Combine(path, assemblyName.Name + ".dll"));
        }
        Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

        // Lastly, reset the ALS entry and remove our handler
        currentAd.SetData(_CurrentAssemblyKey, null);
        //currentAd.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve -= CustomReflectionOnlyResolver; This doesnt work anymore since I added AppDomainSetup  

        return assembly;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can solved by loading dlls in seperate appdomain.

```
private static void ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()
{
    var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Temporary");
    var loader1 = (Loader)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Loader).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
    loader1.Execute(@"D:\somepath\81\MyLib.dll");
    var loader2 = (Loader)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Loader).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
    loader2.Execute(@"D:\somepath\82\MyLib.dll");
    loader1.CompareTwoDLLs(loader2);

    AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
}
```

**Loader.cs**

```
public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Assembly TempAssembly { get; set; }
    public string Execute(string dllPath)
    {
        TempAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllPath);
        return TempAssembly.FullName;
    }
    public void GetRefAssemblyTypes()
    {
        foreach (var refAssembly in TempAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            var asm = Assembly.Load(refAssembly);
            var asmTypes = asm.GetTypes();
        }
    }
    public void CompareTwoDLLs(Loader l2)
    {
        var types1 = TempAssembly.GetTypes();
        var types2= l2.TempAssembly.GetTypes();
        GetRefAssemblyTypes();
        //logic to return comparison result
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi,

I played with your solution, it does work for some basic dll. Once the dll have dependencies it doesn't. I did try to add Assembly.LoadFile for TempAssembly.GetReferenceAssemblies() in the Execute method but it give "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." when trying to do GetTypes().

Comment: Using Loader you can communicate across app domain boundaries. I am able to get the referenced assemblies by adding this method in loader class. Edited my answer with GetRefAssemblyTypes method.